# Design Problem in differential Amp

Tags: analog, differential

It's my first attempt to design CMOS Differential amplifier in 0.35um technology using a cadence tool. I will explain my approach in deriving dimensions of MOSFET's used in it. Moreover, I have also attached my simulation picture for your reference.

I get help from the following reference for calculations:
https://medium.com/@vishnuanugrahith/designing-of-a-cmos-differential-amplifier-68d3d90baae4

**Design Parameters:**

GBW= 10M CL= 10pF, Vdd=5V

UnCox=190u A/V^2; UpCox=55u A/V^2;

Vtn=0.8V Vtp=-1V

Slew Rate(SR) :10V/uSec

Vcmax=4.5V ; Vcmin=1.5V (input common mode range)

**Step 1 _ Calculating Id:**

Id=SR*CL 10V/uSec * 10pF= 100uA

**Step 2 - Calculating (W/L) for M3 and M4:**

Vds1=Vmax-vthn=4.5-0.8=3.7V

Vds3=Vdd-Vds1=5-3.7=1.3V

Id3=Id/2=50uA

(W/L)= 2*Id3/UpCox*vds3=1.075

**Step 3 - Calculating (W/L) for M1 and M2:**

gm1=GBW*2*pi*CL

= 10M*2*3.14*10pF

=6.27*10^-4

Id1=Id/2

(W/L)=gm1^2 / 2*Id1*unCox

=20.75

**Step 4 _ Calculating (W/L) for M5 and M6:**

Vx=(Vmin-Vtn)-Vdsat1

Vdsat1= (2*Id1/UnCox * (W/L)1 )^1/2= 0.16

Vx=0.54

Id5=Id

(W/L) =2*Id5/UnCox * Vx^2= 3.6

**Finally, transistor dimensions are:**

(W/L)1,2 = 1.07u / 1u

(W/L)3,4 = 20.75u / 1u

(W/L)5,6 = 3.6u / 1u

**Differential input Signal:**

Freq= 1 Mhz; Amp= 500 mV; Sine DC level= 2V

**Differential gain:**

= gm2 (ron_n2 || ron_p4)

= 418.5u( 71.73K || 17.04K )

=5.7

1_ I am not getting the output signal according to my calculated gain? I am making mistake in my calculations?

2_ Could anyone comment on my design and mathematical calculations?

3- I am always struggling to find the un*Cox value of MOSFET. after searching in different threads in this and other forums. One way is to find it from betaeff=un*Cox*W/L. But un*Cox changes with changing W/L. So I am always doubtful regarding un*Cox value. Can anybody know the accurate method to find un*Cox value of MOSFET especially using Cadence?

Thanks.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: In my opinion, it is pointless to do a transient analysis, you can see that the output is distorted and the peaks are changing over time. Limit yourself to a OP (operating point) simulation to check the **biasing** of the circuit. When the biasing is OK, do an AC analysis and check the small signal gain. *I am not getting the output signal according to my calculated gain?* Many beginners already complain when theory and simulation figures have a 10% difference **while that's actually pretty good**. Theory and simulation rarely match exactly (why would that be?). But close enough is good enough

Comment: Thanks, @Bimpelrekkie for your suggestion.  
"Limit yourself to an OP" you mean to check the region of operation of all MOSFET's?

Do you have any idea about finding Un*Cox value of MOSFET?

Comment: *you mean to check the region of operation of all MOSFET's* Yes, realize that you only need **one** transistor biased incorrectly to get unexpected results. You're over worrying about Cox, Cox is a process parameter so go look in the design manual. You can also use: Results => Print Operating Parameters and see a whole list of properties and values for a MOSFET for the biasing conditions of that transistor.